# SAP DBTech JDBC: [260]: invalid column name - SQL for HANA (Studio) and SQL SERVER (MST) produces differents results

Tags: hana

I have this query in SQL Server and it's ok ... but in Hana Studio it throws an error

> SAP DBTech JDBC: [260]: invalid column name: VT.ItemCode: line 23 col 15

Can you help me? Thanks

```
SELECT
    VT."ItemCode" AS "ItemCode", VT."PN" AS PN,
    SUM(VT."Qty") AS Qty, SUM(VT."Valor") AS Valor 
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            T1."ItemCode" AS ItemCode, T0."CardCode" AS PN, 
            T1."Quantity" AS Qty, T1."LineTotal" AS Valor
        FROM
            OINV T0
        INNER JOIN 
            INV1 T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry"
        WHERE 
            T0."DocDate" >= ('2018-01-01') AND T0."DocDate" <= ('2018-12-31')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            T1."ItemCode" AS ItemCode, T0."CardCode" AS PN, 
            -1 * T1."Quantity" AS Qty, -1 * T1."LineTotal" AS Valor
        FROM
            ORIN T0
        INNER JOIN
            RIN1 T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry"
        LEFT JOIN
            INV1 T2 ON T1."BaseType" = T2."ObjType" 
                    AND T1."BaseEntry" = T2."DocEntry" 
                    AND T1."BaseLine" = T2."LineNum"
        WHERE 
            T0."DocDate" >= ('2018-01-01') AND T0."DocDate" <= ('2018-12-31')
    ) AS VT
GROUP BY 
    ItemCode, PN
```

Comment: Avoid quoted identifiers if you can. Then you will never have such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since column `ItemCode` has lower case characters it needs to be referenced with double quotation marks. This includes the `GROUP BY` clause.

It’s correct in the list of projected columns, just needs to be done the same way at the end of the statement.